# Hyphenation of first Author in Apacite

Tags: hyphenation, apa-style

I'm using `apacite` for my bibliography and for in-text citations. Unfortunately the *first* Author in a multi-author citation does not get hyphenated.

Is there anything I can do to make everything in an apacite `\cite` or `\citeA` hyphenatable? (I dont see any point in not hyphenating the first author's name.)

```
\documentclass[11pt, paper=a5, DIV17, BCOR1cm, draft]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[unnumberedbib,tocbib,nosectionbib,bibnewpage,nodoi]{apacite}   [2012/02/25]
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

\minisec{Grundlage für den Erwerb fachdidaktischen Wissens}
Fachliches Wissen gewinnt seine Bedeutung für Lehrkräfte als die Grundlage, "`auf der fachdidaktische Beweglichkeit entsteht"' \cite[S.~27]{BaumertKunter2006}. Für die Lehramtsausbildung bedeutet dies, dass fachliches Wissen als eine wesentliche Grundlage für den Erwerb fachdidaktischen Wissens gesehen wird (Krauss et al., 2008, Terhart, 2002). Lersch (2006, S.~117) zeigt darüber hinaus auf, dass Referendare das fachliche Wissen für wesentlich relavanter für die Bewältigung ihrer aktuellen Aufgaben halten, als die anderen beiden Wissensbereiche.

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Content of bibliographie.bib:

```
@article{BaumertKunter2006,
 author = {Baumert, J{\"u}rgen and Kunter, Mareike},
 year = {2006},
 title = {{Stichwort: Professionelle Kompetenz von Lehrkr{\"a}ften}},
 pages = {469--520},
 volume = {9},
 number = {4},
 issn = {1434-663X},
 journal = {{Zeitschrift f{\"u}r Erziehungswissenschaft}}
}
```

**EDIT:** I have added a more realistic paragraph to the MWE to reflect the problem. Additionally I observe that this effect does *not* occur, when I use `filecontents` to produce the `\jobname.bib` file. It *does* occur with [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/601851/LineBreak.bib) file. Results [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/601851/LineBreak.pdf) Maybe a problem with the file encoding?

Unfortunately I am not able to insert `\-` hyphenation hints into my bib file, because I produce it with a third party bibliography management system which I also use for non-LaTeX projects.

Comment: @Mico, @Kurt added a more realistic example. The problem still occurs mid-paragraph but not with `filecontents`.

Comment: Thanks for rewriting your posting to provide a more realistic example of the issues you're facing. I've rewritten my answer in response. My recommendation is that you (a) provide the option `natbibapa` when loading the `apacite` package and (b) use the citation commands of the `natbib` package, viz, `\citep` and `\citet`. The user guide of the `apacite` manual speaks favorably of using the `natbibapa` option, by the way, so this isn't just some hackish solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Remark: I rewrote this answer completely after the OP posted a more realistic example of the hyphenation problems he encountered when using the `\cite` macro of the `apacite` package.)

There may well be a bug in the way the `apacite` package has implemented the `\cite` command. I therefore suggest you provide the option `natbibapa` when loading the `apacite` package -- doing so loads the `natbib` package in a way that assures interoperability with `apacite`'s own macros -- and use `natbib`'s `\citep` macro instead of `\cite` to create the citation call-out. At least for the example you've provided, there's no longer a lack-of-hyphenation problem with the work "Baumert" if you make this change.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, paper=a5, DIV17, BCOR1cm, draft]{scrbook}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{BaumertKunter2006,
 author = {Baumert, J{\"u}rgen and Kunter, Mareike},
 year = {2006},
 title = {{Stichwort: Professionelle Kompetenz von Lehrkr{\"a}ften}},
 pages = {469--520},
 volume = {9},
 number = {4},
 issn = {1434-663X},
 journal = {Zeitschrift f{\"u}r Erziehungswissenschaft}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}

\usepackage[unnumberedbib,tocbib,nosectionbib,bibnewpage,
            nodoi,natbibapa  % "natbibapa" is new
           ]{apacite}[2012/02/25]
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}

\minisec{Grundlage für den Erwerb fachdidaktischen Wissens}

Fachliches Wissen gewinnt seine Bedeutung für Lehrkräfte als die Grundlage, "`auf 
der fachdidaktische Beweglichkeit entsteht"' \citep[S.~27]{BaumertKunter2006}. Für 
%% note the use of "\citep`" to create the citation call-out
die Lehramtsausbildung bedeutet dies, dass fachliches Wissen als eine wesentliche 
Grundlage für den Erwerb fachdidaktischen Wissens gesehen wird (Krauss et al., 2008, 
Terhart, 2002). Lersch (2006, S.~117) zeigt darüber hinaus auf, dass Referendare das 
fachliche Wissen für wesentlich relavanter für die Bewältigung ihrer aktuellen 
Aufgaben halten, als die anderen beiden Wissensbereiche.

\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This answer works on my side and I will use this method in later work. Currently I am adding the last pages to a ~350 pages book (60 pages bibliography) and I can hardly imagine turning maybe 1000 cite* macros around. :-(

Comment: @DavidWoitkowski - No need to change all 1000+ `\cite` commands. Modifying just the few instances that are causing hyphenation problems should do the job, right?

Comment: unfortunately not: with `natbibapa`, `\citeA{}` and friends are not loaded. Even with `apaciteclassic` as additional option. It seems to be either or.

Comment: @DavidWoitkowski - Can you do a global search-and-replace of `\citeA` with `\citet`, followed by a similar transformation from `\cite` to `\citep`? The `\citeauthor` and `\citeyear` commands are identical across `natbib` and `apacite`, as far as I can tell.